# Is there an easyier way to publish silverlight & wcf services from localhost to IIS?

Tags: silverlight, iis, wcf, localhost, publish

Is there a simpler way to deploy/publish silverlight & wcf projects from localhost enviroment to a IIS server?

I have a web project with a self host wcf service which my silverlight application references.  When I work locally I set the reference address to htt://localhost:8080/MyService.svc -and when I want to put it on the IIS server, I reference its address htt:///MyService.svc   everything works which is good. -and in fact, I event put a clientaccesspolicy file on root of the site too just incase i need to do a test connect from my desktop/laptop.

Its getting a bit tiresome, having to  change it each time.  Surely this is quite a common thing? Is there a setting somewhere that allows me to swap configuartions when deploying/publishing? -similar to that of the (Debug / Release) solution configuration.

Any thoughts, pointers or recommended practices would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Ahh  I've answer my own question.. for those looking to do something similar -try the following...  http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/11/04/configswitcher-servicereferences-clientconfig-switcher-utility.aspx   (also have a look at the comments section  -as Matt Watson has a good suggestion also)

Comment: this is the other link ...
http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2009/02/23/silverlight-servicereferences-clientconfig-alternatives.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you will deploy it to the IIS: why don't you just use the host of visual studio creating a not self hosted wcf service? new project --> WCF --> WCF Service Application.

In the other hand, for managing environments dependent configs I like this thing:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx